# Is it possible to create a html site as responsive as awordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, responsive

I've been looking for ways to make my web designs as responsive as WordPress, as I've seen with WordPress the content grows and shrinks as soon as the window gets resized even into extremely small windows like 100px width windows, seemingly without many media queries. Is it possible to make a site this responsive with just pure HTML, CSS and Javascript?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can control this responsive resizing e.g. with the media only screen and max with properties via CSS and then adapt the CSS code to fit your needs. Thats a quick and easy start in responsiveness. You can have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 16px
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 14px
  }
}
```

There are definetly way better options, but this one is very simple.

Comment: What're the better options?